# Create a complete java HttpResponse object including headers from a String

Tags: java, servlets

I have a HttpServlet class that delegates to a script which returns the response as a String. The String includes the headers for example:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
<!DOCTYPE html...
```

Can I populate the HttpServletResponse somehow with this? or even create a new HttpServletResponse object from this String or do I have no choice but to parse the String manually and set the headers and body separately?

Comment: I could be mistaken, but the headers are key/value pairs?  Could you not split the `String` at the `:` token and set the headers?

Comment: @MadProgrammer sure, but I'm trying to avoid parsing and reconstructing the response if I can.

Comment: You can't create a new instance of response ; use the available one

Answer (score 0):

HttpServlet doesn't have a constructor which accepts a header in String form and initializes all its fields.
You have to parse the string value by value and call

```
void addHeader(java.lang.String name, java.lang.String value)
```

Alternatively you could use a library to parse HTTP headers like BasicHeaderValueParser in HttpCore 4.2 (see Apache HttpComponents http://hc.apache.org/), but that might be overkill if you just want to parse one header.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the code of any open source servlet container (tomcat, jetty, etc...) and find the class that parse the HTTP content in order to build the HttpRequest/HttpResponse objects.